# Why do my circles on pygame keep despawning and re-spawning?

Tags: python, pygame, display

When I run this program I want the game to spawn one larger movable dot and hundreds of smaller non-movable dots at random locations. However, when I run the program the smaller dots keep despawning and respawning. I think it has something to do with the pygame.display.update() function but I am not entirely sure. How do I fix this problem?

```
from pygame import *
import random as rd

p_1_x = 200
p_1_y = 200
p_1_change_x = 0

init()
screen = display.set_mode((800, 600))


def p_1(x, y):
    player_1 = draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (x, y), 15)


def drawwing():
    for i in range(0, 250):
        x = rd.randint(100, 700)
        y = rd.randint(100, 500)
        dot = draw.circle(screen, (55, 255, 155), (x, y), 5)


while True:
    for events in event.get():
        if events.type == QUIT:
            quit()
        if events.type == KEYDOWN:
            if events.key == K_RIGHT:
                p_1_change_x = 1
            if events.key == K_LEFT:
                p_1_change_x = -1

        if events.type == KEYUP:
            if events.key == K_RIGHT or K_LEFT:
                p_1_change_x = 0
                p_1_change_y = 0

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    p_1_x += p_1_change_x

    p_1(p_1_x, p_1_y)
    display.update()
    drawwing()
    display.update()
```

Comment: It is your program, not pygame.  You are explicitly calling you drawwing() function every time through your loop!  If you want a static starfield in the back room, you have to save the positions of all the little dots, or generate them with a repeatable algorithm, not with randint().

Comment: What would be the best way to save their positions?

Comment: See my answer for one possible solution. Note: you don't need both update calls.  Also if you want the big dot to appear in front of the small dots, draw it after, not before, the small dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want stationary dots, use something like this instead:

```
dots = list((rd.randint(100,700),rd.randint(100,500)) for i in range(0,250))

def drawwing():
    for x,y in dots:
        draw.circle(screen, (55, 255, 155), (x, y), 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a class for dots:

```
class Dot():
    SIZE = 5
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self):
        draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), Dot.SIZE)
```

Then I made an array and generate `NUMBER_OF_DOTS` like this:

```
dots = []

for i in range(NUMBER_OF_DOTS):
    x = rd.randint(100, 700)
    y = rd.randint(100, 500)
    dots.append(Dot(x,y))
```

and in the `while` loop, after filling the whole scene by white color, redraw all dots like this:

```
while True:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    ...
    for dot in dots:
        dot.draw()
```

Happy Coding
https://github.com/peymanmajidi/Ball-And-Dots-Game__Pygame